# Objective-C ARC and Legacy Runtime compiling error

Tags: objective-c, xcode, compilation, compiler-errors, clang

I'm trying to compile sources with Xcode 4.6, for 32bit architecture, but getting this error:

```
error: -fobjc-arc is not supported on platforms using the legacy runtime
Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You're mixing ARC (automatic reference counting) with the older Objective-C 1.0 runtime, which does not support ARC.

32-bit apps on OSX, automatically use the 1.0 Runtime, so you'll have to disable ARC for your project, and use Manual Reference Counting.

Comment: What if the message appears when compiling an iOS app?

Comment: More than likely, you are targeting your iOS app to an older version of iOS which doesn't support ARC.

Comment: Also, Visual Source Safe is the devil.

Comment: My OSX app is targeted for `64-bit Intel` and I'm still seeing this error.

Comment: Is this still the case, that ARC is 64-bit only?

Answer (score 2):

This problem recently resurfaced because Xcode 5 removes the ARCHS parameter - if you let it. But if you have a build server with Xcode 4 this defaults there to building 32 and 64 bit, which fails if you have ARC enabled.

See my [writeup](http://www.cocoanetics.com/2013/10/fobj-arc-is-not-supported-on-platforms-using-the-legacy-runtime/) for a more detailed explanation.