# XCode Objective-C - Legacy to Modern

Tags: objective-c, xcode

Exhausted a search but could not find a good answer, so my apologies if this is a duplicate question...

I'm using Xcode 4.6 on OS X 10.8.5 and am in the process or learning objective-c via treehouse. When compiling a very simple application I get the following errors:

error: -fobjc-arc is not supported on platforms using the legacy runtime

Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1

After some google searching I haven't found much in terms of how to fix this error. I'm only left with leaning on the obvious... I need to update my objective-c runtime from legacy to modern.

The biggest problem is I have no idea how to change my runtime from legacy to modern and have xcode use the 'modern' objective-c runtime.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: That's a bizarre error. How was the project created? Have you tried removing redownloading Xcode?

Comment: What's your target SDK? Have you seen [ObjC ARC and legacy runtime compiling error](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15214601)?

Comment: Thank you that link helped a ton. Simply upgrading to Xcode 5 fixed this bug.